# Open Modal from Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and am using the Modal JS plugin. I have a modal which is open and want to open another modal from the original modal that is open.

The reasoning, is the user can select an option from the dropdown list. If the item they want to select isn't in the list, they can click a button and add a new one.

I've tried to hide the original modal, then show the new one, but I get stuck with just showing the backdrop. When I try and open them together, the backdrop gets dark (since I've now placed another backdrop on top of the one already existing and I can still see the original modal.

Ideally I could open a modal, then open another just as easy as doing it today with one modal.

Comment: Stacking dialogs is very cumbersome. Why not have a hidden input field in the existing modal that displays when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was the 2nd modal was inside the file of the first, so when I hid the first, I couldn't show the 2nd one (which is why I was left with just the backdrop). I ended up just calling modal.('hide') on the first modal, then modal('show') on the 2nd.