# Opening a modal window from an already opened modal window in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a modal window from an already opened modal window in Angular JS. Briefly, I have a home page, from the home page which is basically a list page, when a user double clicks on a record in the list, a modal window opens up which has got three buttons - Save, Delete & Cancel. Clicking on the Delete button requires to open another modal window which would let the user to delete that record. Following is the code for the same :

home.html : This is the main page having a grid displaying multiple records in list view

{

```
    ...........
    .......... Grid rendering code starts her
    <div class="table-body-container">
      <table class="table table-hover table-without-bottom">
        <colgroup ng-repeat="header in headers" class="{{header.columnSize}}" ng-show="header.selected">
          <tbody ng-repeat="rccs in records">
            <tr ng-repeat="ri in rccs.recordcodes">
            ..............
            <td **ng-dblclick="editModal(ri)**" ng-show="headers[1].selected">{{ri.recordCodeType}}</td>
          ............
    ............
          ....
          </tbody>
        </colgroup>
      </table>
    </div>
...............
................
**<div ng-controller="ri.controller.EditCtrl"
  class="modal fade"
  ng-class="{'in' : editModalOpen}"
  ng-include="'resources/ri/views/editRI.html'">**
 </div>
.......................
```

}

In the above bold part, double clicking opens up a modal window. The .js part is below :

homectrl.js - the method editModal in this controller sets the editModalOpen to true which triggers the first modal window

{

```
......
.......
$scope.editModal = function(row) {
  $scope.updateRow = row;
  $scope.editModalOpen = true;
}
```

}

The template for the first modal window is "editRI.html" which has the following :

editRI.html
{

```
.........
......
<div class="modal-footer">
  ......Cancel button HTML
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteModal()">Delete</button>
...............
.........
    **<div ng-controller="ri.controller.EditCtrl"
      class="modal fade"
      ng-class="{'in' : deleteModalOpen}"
      ng-include="'resources/ri/views/deleteRI.html'">**
     </div>
```

}

The above html in the editRI template is supposed to open another modal window on top of the existing modal window so that the user can perform a delete operation for the record. I have checked these links already and made the changes accordingly but it did not work : 
- http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/ - I could not do much here as I also need to follow the standards that my team has followed in opening a dialog.
- [Open Modal from Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571964/open-modal-from-modal/9584430#9584430)  - This looked to be exactly the similar case as mine, but the answer was not clear enough. I tried putting the html for the 2nd modal window in a separate file and tried but dint work.

Can someone please give some pointers to me as per the above code ????

Comment: I speak from personal experience when I say that opening modals from other modals (in Bootstrap especially) is path that leads to extreme sorrow and dissatisfaction with the solution you'll come up with. My advice is to consider not opening modals from other modals.

Comment: I could have done it in some other way, but the project requires this behavior which is as per the business requirements given. Hence, trying to find out a way to get this done.

Comment: @user3542818 - is a single modal with a wizard-like behavior (next, previews, ...) can be considered as option?

Comment: Can someone please provide some pointers to this scenario ?